# Django Pipleline is generating empty css and js files

Tags: django

I am facing an issue Django Pipeline is generating empty files not writing the content of files..

is my settings

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
  'main2': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'vendor/introJs/introjs.css',
        'vendor/introjs-theme-royal.css',


    ),
    'output_filename': 'css/main2.min.css',
     'variant': 'datauri',
  },
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
  'main': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'js/libs/jquery.js',
        'js/libs/lodash.js',
        'js/libs/json2.js',
        'js/libs/*.js',
        #'vendor/jqueryui/js/*.js',
        'js/plugins/*.js',
        'js/tools.js',
        'js/models.js',
        'js/modules/*.js',
        'js/main.js',

    ),
    'output_filename': 'js/main.min.js',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check `PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR`, `PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR` probably your compressor is not working propoerly, try these value to test it:

```
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.NoopCompressor' 
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.NoopCompressor'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)
```

pipeline by default uses Yuglify (see https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compressors.html)

Comment: I have used every thing inside the pipeline even Yuglify still the files are empty I don't know why :( :(

Comment: not sure to understand. did u try the NoopCompressor ? What is the value of `STATICFILES_STORAGE` ?

Comment: Yes I tried it , but it is also generating empty files

Comment: What is the value of STATICFILES_STORAGE ? Can you post the values of all the settings (PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR, PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR, STATICFILES_STORAGE, STATICFILES_FINDERS, PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY)

Comment: I am using this setting                                                              STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True
PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.cssmin.CSSMinCompressor'
PIPELINE_CSSMIN_BINARY = 'cssmin'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.slimit.SlimItCompressor'
PIPELINE = True
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.cssmin.CSSMinCompressor'